# What are these 99+% peaks in Google Cloud VM CPU Usage?

Tags: linux, wordpress, cloud, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

So i got a Google Cloud VM which is running a woocommerce store. It works fine but now i got this problem for the second time. The VM's **CPU Usage** suddenly goes **over 99%** for a long period of time. During that time the site is basically offline.

When i stop the VM and then restart it it goes back to normal CPU usage which is **<1%** most of time and **1 - 10%** some periods of time.

Also when i use `sudo kill` with the process id's of the `.php-fpm.bin` it solves the problem for a few hours but then it starts running the `.php-fpm.bin` again under a different PID.

Also when i use `killall` on .php-fpm.bin the website goes down altogether.

This is a **big issue** which can turn very bad very soon and i'm a beginner with servers.

**Any help** with the root cause of this will be **very very much appreciated!**

**--EDIT--**

Here is my CPU usage shown using '`top`' on SSH:

[result top on ssh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6v3r.png)

Something unusual is going on with **.php-fpm.bin**, anybody got an idea of what i might be?

This is visible when i type `ps aux`in SSH:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
daemon   10048 99.9  0.9 286860 71564 ?        R    13:13  83:15 php-fpm: pool wordpress
```

If you need any other monitoring stats please do tell me what you need to know and i will look it up for you.

Comment: These PHP processes are using up all the CPU resources indeed. Did you look at your web server access and error logs? Also your `php-fpm` logs?

Comment: Did you check your programming? Some pages may run processor bound loops that never end due to programming errors.

Comment: You might want to have a look at these two posts [1](https://community.bitnami.com/t/mysqld-bin-and-php-fpm-eating-up-all-my-cpu-c3-large/27015/3),[2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732436/php5-fpm-randomly-starts-consuming-a-lot-of-cpu)

Comment: I saw those posts already, they didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Have you looked at your access logs (try filtering by wp-login.php) and error logs to see if there is a correlation between a spike in access (likely login bruteforce attempts into WP) and php-fpm using a lot of CPU? Do you see any sigkills during these periods of high CPU usage?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. This is the first im using a vm and i have no idea where to look for these logs.. The spikes do seem to start when multiple users log in to wp-admin.

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat: I'm also not a server / sysadmin person but had to dive in earlier this year.*

I've encountered performance issues like this when running node.js processes. It's possible there are parallels to what you're seeing. In my case, based on changes I experimented with it looks to have been related to hitting max pages limits.

These are configuration changes I performed that helped resolve issues:

In /etc/security/limits.d/custom.conf

```
root soft nofile 1000000
root hard nofile 1000000
* soft nofile 1000000
* hard nofile 1000000
```

In /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf

```
fs.file-max = 1000000
fs.nr_open = 1000000
net.nf_conntrack_max = 1048576
```

To update running processes:

```
sudo sysctl -w fs.file-max=1000000
sudo sysctl -w fs.nr_open=1000000
sudo sysctl -w net.nf_conntrack_max=1048576
```

As root:

```
ulimit -n 1000000
```

You're milage may vary based on what's managing your processes.

Here's some documentation with further sysctl tweaks, some of which I plan to research and implement: https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/sysctl-conf/

Comment: Didn't work for me, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

@luissimo This server has no swap space (see top headings), so it can't swap processes out. Allocate a disk (probably minimum 200Gb).You have 8Gb memory. So use fdisk to partition the disk in two, say 1st partition of 16Gb as swap area, 2nd partition the rest. See if that helps.

Comment: How would that possibly help? Without swap space the server runs into memory problems if it is out of memory. That would result in processes terminating - but not high CPU usage, or? This looks a lot more like soemthinc causing high CPU usage, for example google coming around and crawling.